# select browser in webview without android native code

Tags: webview

can I open(or select) another browser in my hybrid app(using webview)
without native android code(ex. intent)?

My web page have code like this

```
<a href="something.com" target="_blank"> click </a>
```

when click that link, i wanna browser select menu like chrome , internet, etc...
but when i click that link, it only open in my browser.

and i tried with javascript

```
window.open("something.com", "_blank");
```

but it dosen't work too
how can i solve this problem?